# Fastest way to update paragraph in RichTextBox's FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument, paragraph

I would update a paragraph in a FlowDocument (in a RichTextBox).

Currectly, I use, each time, the function Clear() to empty the blocks and, then, fill the RichTextBox.Document.Blocks with my paragraph.

But, clearing and adding each time my paragraph, it's very slow and I lost a lot of performance to do that. How optimize these instructions and update efficiently the paragraph in RichTextBox ?

Thank's

Comment: Did you try replacing the contents of only the Paragraph object you want to change?

Comment: My issue is, for example, when I add a letter from an input key in the RichTextBox, I suppose (not sure) that the RichTextBox, on this event, create a new FlowDocument (or Paragraph I don't know exactly) internally. It don't use the same paragraph that I used in code behind. So what I do, it's to insert the new letter in the text in my own paragraph then clear the flowdocument in richtextbox and fill it with my own paragraph to have the good text. Each time. I'm sure there is a better way (and faster). I hope I give you more precisions to answer. Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I suspect it is the run within the paragraph that is changing not the paragraph.

If you are creating the paragraph/runs in code you may have not set the language.

If you have a run without language set and you type in a RichTextBox the runs get split where you type to create 3 runs.

Set the language on the Run/Paragraph to your locale e.g. en-gb or en-us

```
var run = new Run("Test") {Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("en-us") };
```

If you now type in the middle of the run no new runs/paragraphs will be added.

Comment: Thank's ! But set the language doesn't help me. When I type a letter in RichTextBox, i see the associate Run in code behind become null. So yes, it's the Run and not Paragraph that is changing ! Thank's